# List of records to assign to X number of people

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have list of records which I want to assign to three people (eg.) equally.

So for example with 15 records, to split to three people named XYZ, PQR and ABC:

```
Case  Name
123   XYZ
124   XYZ
135   XYZ
138   ABC
145   ABC
167   ABC
258   PQR
259   PQR
260   PQR
```

Comment: Formulas, code, logical approach any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Take a good look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It is not clear from your data what you want. This is not a place to **get code** but for others to help with what **you** have done so far. You will get more help if you outline some code and then ask for help for the last stretch.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your Comment, if `Case` is in A1 and three people's names are in F2:F4 (ie in Column4) please try in B2 and copied down to suit:

```
=OFFSET(B$2,INT(ROW()-2)/COUNTA(F:F)-COUNTA(F:F)*INT((ROW()-2)/COUNTA(F:F)^2),4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of `Cases` to be assigned *“equally”* over a pool of `People`.
However, the `Cases` can only be assigned *“equally”* is their number is an exact multiple of the number of `People`, otherwise the residual cases will be assigned as per the order in the list of people, i.e. if you have 31 cases to be distributed among 4 individuals, then three people will have 8 cases while the remaining one will receive 7.

Assuming the list of `Cases` *(including header)* is located at `B6:B40` and the list of `People` *(also with header)* is at `G6:G10`, and blank records, if any, are at the end of each list. *(These formulas will work with Cases coded as numeric or alpha)*

1. To assign the cases one by one to each person enter the following `FormulaArray` in the range `C7:C40` 
   *(Formulas Array are entered by pressing `[Ctrl]` + `[Shift]` + `[Enter]` together)*

   ```
   =IF($B$7:$B$40="","",INDEX($G$7:$G$10,
   1+MOD(-1+COUNTA($G$7:$G$10)
   +(1+ROW($B$7:$B$40)-ROW($B$7)),
   COUNTA($G$7:$G$10))))
   ```

[image]

Fig. 1

2. To assign the cases using the pattern shown in the sample data we need first to add a field to the list of persons in order to calculate the distribution of the cases *(this makes the formula to allocate people easier to read, maintain  and shorter)* . In cell `H6` enter the field name `Count` then  in range `H7:H10` enter this `FormulaArray`:

   ```
   =IF($G$7:$G$10="","",
   INT(COUNTA($B$7:$B$40)/COUNTA($G$7:$G$10))
   +((1+ROW($G$7:$G$10)-ROW($G$7))<=
   MOD(COUNTA($B$7:$B$40),COUNTA($G$7:$G$10)))*1)
   ```

[image]

Fig. 2

```
Then enter this `FormulaArray` in `E7` and copy to the end of the range.

    =IFERROR(IF($B7="","",
    IF(COUNTIF($G$7:$G$10,$E6)=0,
    INDEX($G$7:$G$10,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(E$6:E6,$G$7:$G$10),0)*1),
    IF(COUNTIF($E$6:$E6,$E6)<INDEX($H$7:$H$10,MATCH($E6,$G$7:$G$10,0)),$E6,
    INDEX($G$7:$G$10,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(E$6:E6,$G$7:$G$10),0)*1)))),"")
```

[image]

Fig. 3